# angular home page redirect with / for query parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am running my angular app on

```
localhost:4200
```

when I want query params

like

```
localhost:4200?id=1
```

it changed to

```
localhost:4200/?id=1
```

I don't want / in my URL , how can we achieve that

I will deploy my app in node js with route

```
app.get("/portal",load my ANGULAR BUILD)
```

so final URL will be

```
localhost:3000/portal/?id=99
```

but I want

```
localhost:3000/portal?id=99
```

Comment: something like the following doesn't fit for your needs?

const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: ':website', 
    component: EntryComponent, 
    pathMatch: 'prefix', 
    children: [
        { path: 'info', component: InfoComponent },
        { path: 'contact', component:  ContactComponent},
    ],  
    resolve:  {
      config: RemoteConfigResolver
    }
  },
  
  { path: '', component: DefaultComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

Comment: @bark-at-the-moon no , cant use / in node application as it is pre occupied